# WMI query: select all processes under specific username?

Tags: vba, wmi

I have this code in VBA:

```
strTerminateThis = "notepad.exe"
Set objList = objWMIcimv2.ExecQuery _
("select * from win32_process where name='" & strTerminateThis & "'")
```

I want to narrow this query down by adding another `where` to select a specific username that process is running under.

How can this be done? While `name` is the name of the process, I wasn't able to find something simple like `pid_owner`.

My goal would be to count how many Notepad processes are open under a specific user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't expose any property related to the owner of the process, so you only option is list all the procesess and then filter manually calling the method [`GetOwner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
.